# Balancing words

Tags: strings, ruby, programming-challenge

> A word is balanced at the index if the sum of the alphabet positions of all the chars multiplied by the distance to the index is zero.

This description is equivalent to the one given by [DailyProgrammer](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/3c9a9h/) in the challenge info.

I did not code Input/Output as I found them not as interesting as the logic.

The code works for the given testcase.

```
def balanced_at?(string, index, alphabet=("a".."z").to_a)
  string
    .chars
    .each_with_index
    .map { |char, char_index| (alphabet.index(char) + 1) * (char_index - index)}
    .inject(:+)
    .zero?
end

def balanced_where(string)
  (0..string.length)
    .detect {|index| balanced_at?(string, index)}
end

puts balanced_where("stead")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You may use splat operator instead of `.to_a`
2. You may use `.map.with_index` instead of `.each_with_index.map`
3. You should (bug?) use `...` instead of `..`

```rb
def balanced_at? string, index, alphabet = [*"a".."z"]
  string.chars.map.with_index do |char, char_index|
    (alphabet.index(char) + 1) * (char_index - index)
  end.inject(:+).zero?
end

def balanced_where string
  (0...string.length).detect do |index|
    balanced_at? string, index
  end
end

puts balanced_where "stead"
```

But note, that your function is monotone, so you may get a perfomance profit by using *find-any mode* of `.bsearch` instead of `.detect`:

```
def balance string, index, alphabet = [*"a".."z"]
  string.chars.map.with_index do |char, char_index|
    (alphabet.index(char) + 1) * (char_index - index)
  end.inject(:+)
end

def balanced_where string
  (0...string.length).bsearch do |index|
    balance string, index
  end
end
```

Read [`Array#bsearch` docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) for explanation.

Comment: 1. The same, not an improvement 2. ditto as 1 3. "z"  is a letter of the alphabet (in Ruby `..` is inclusive): `irb(main):006:0> ("a".."z").to_a
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"] `4. _your function is monotone_ wrong, my function returns something like `[false, true, false, false]` that is not ok according to, citing the docs: 
`the block returns false for any element whose index is less than i, and

    the block returns true for any element whose index is greater than or equal to i.`

Comment: 3. I mean `0..string.length` 4. your function is monotone, until you wrap it in `.zero?` -- do not do it.

Comment: Yes I think including the ending length is a bug considering that ruby will return nil at `array[array.length]`, not wrapping it in zero is good and leads to refactoring: `def balancement_value(string, index, alphabet=("a".."z").to_a)
  string
  .chars
  .each_with_index
  .map { |char, char_index| (alphabet.index(char) + 1) * (char_index - index)}
  .inject(:+)
end` and then `def balanced_at?(string, index, alphabet=("a".."z").to_a)
  balancement_value(string, index, alphabet=("a".."z").to_a).zero?
end` I will call `balancement_value` from `balanced_where` (Ps: why this formatting?)